# How come this select/group by query works?

Tags: postgresql

I expected this query to not work on Postgres, but it works fine:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY users.id
```

How come it works? I am selecting fields that I am not grouping by. The table contains tens of columns.

I am using Postgres.app on OSX, version 9.3.3.0 (21).

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? All fields are getting group by users.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are grouping by a column on which all others are functional dependent on:

[Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the **ungrouped column is functionally dependent** on the grouped columns [...].  A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

This complies with the SQL standard and has been added in Postgres 9.1

Comment: which was added in version 9.1

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I guess I remembered it not working from an older version of PG.